# Checking earned companion perks?

Tags: fallout-4

Is there anywhere in game to check your earned companion perks? I don't see companion perks listed on the Perks Chart, was wondering if there was anywhere else they might be listed?

Answer (score 10):

I figured out how to find the companion perks earned, can't believe I missed it.

On your Pip-Boy (Press B on XBOX 1)
On the STAT tab 
Switch subtab to PERKS (Twice Right on the D-pad)

This menu subtab lists all the perks you've purchased with XP plus the perks earned through companions and perks found including issues of Grognak, Astoundingly Awesome Tales, Live & Love, Wasteland Survival Guide, and others as well as US Covert Ops Manuals.

[image: in game screenshot of Perks menu on Pip-Boy]

Answer (score -3):

Perks are only listed if they are active. You would either have to keep track yourself of which ones you've unlocked. Or if you aren't sure and haven't kept track if you have a particular followers perk, you can have them follow you then check your active perks.

Comment: [Companion Perks are permanent, whether they are follow you or not](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perks#Companion_perks). 'Lover's Embrace' is counted as a 'Temporary Perk' because it *does* require a loving companion to be nearby

Comment: @Robotnik Lover's Embrace is also a temporary perk because it only lasts a certain amount of time after taking a rest with your "lover" nearby.

Comment: @Robotnik "Lover's Embrace" requires a romantically-involved _character_ to be nearby _when you rest_. There are two important distinctions here - 1.) They don't have to be a companion; there's a lounge singer you can flirt with and take her to bed. 2.) They have to be there when you rest, you don't have to keep them with you. I keep my romanced Cait at Sanctunary, but I use other companions in the field.